# How to structure a service correctly to use Windsor?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

```
class CustomService(IProcessor processor) : ICustomService
```

The class `CustomService` has a dependency that will be injected. There are multiple implementations for `IProcessor`.  Which implementation that should be used is determined by a setting that is stored in a database for the current user.

At first, I thought about implementing an `IHandlerSelector` that would retrieve the setting from the database and determine which implementation to use.  But there is business logic for cases where the setting is missing from the database, etc....  Since there is business logic, I'm not sure it would be correct to put this in the `IHandlerSelector`.

I thought about creating another class called `TopService`:

```
class TopService(ISettingsProvider provider, IProcessorFactory procFactory, ICustomServiceFactory serviceFactory)
```

`TopService` uses two typed factories. It would use `ISettingsProvider` to retreive the settings from the database and use the `IProcessorFactory` to resolve the appropriate `IProcessor`.  After I have the correct `IProcessor`, I would use the `ICustomServiceFactory` factory to resolve `CustomService`.

However, this seems a little off to me.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `TopService` approach looks good to me... as long as that's not its real name :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the `IProcessorFactory` into the `CustomerService` class?  This would still isolate your `CustomerService` class from the implementation of your `IProcessorFactory`.  That way if your business logic to select the proper `IProcessor` changed in the future you could just create a new `IProcessorFactory`.

I would imagine it being something like this:

```
public interface IProcessorFactory {
     IProcessor GetProcessor();
     IProcessor GetProcessor(string processorType);
}
```

Then in your `CustomerService` class could call the correct `GetProcessor()` method depending on whether or not the setting is provided for the customer.